How to remove emojis on filenames or usernames?
I have an issue with my emoji remover method.
This method is used when downloading chat transcripts and checks for any emojis in the username, removing them if present. It works in the local and staging environments. But in the live environment, it sometimes works for transcripts with the same username but fails on others.
This is the error I got for code point U+1F413, ROOSTER.
2024-09-26 16:17:20.877 ERROR [whatsapp-api-service,64b76bd04750daa2,64b76bd04750daa2] 3200902 --- [http-nio-8002-exec-2] z.c.e.p.s.UUIDAuthenticationFilter       : Request processing failed; nested exception is Error downloading transcript, U+1F413 ('.notdef') is not available in the font Helvetica, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is Error downloading transcript, U+1F413 ('.notdef') is not available in the font Helvetica, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

after removing that emoji manually via the database I was able to download the transcript for that specific user
This the code.
private static final List<UnicodeRange> EMOJI_RANGES = Arrays.asList(
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F600, 0x1F64F),  // Emoticons
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F300, 0x1F5FF),  // Misc Symbols and Pictographs
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F680, 0x1F6FF),  // Transport and Map Symbols
            new UnicodeRange(0x2600, 0x26FF),    // Misc Symbols
            new UnicodeRange(0x2700, 0x27BF),    // Dingbats
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F900, 0x1F9FF),  // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
            new UnicodeRange(0x1FA70, 0x1FAFF),  // Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F1E6, 0x1F1FF),  // Regional Indicator Symbols
            new UnicodeRange(0xFE00, 0xFE0F),    // Variation Selectors
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F000, 0x1F02F),  // Mahjong Tiles
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F0A0, 0x1F0FF),  // Playing Cards
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F700, 0x1F77F),  // Alchemical Symbols
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F780, 0x1F7FF),  // Geometric Shapes Extended
            new UnicodeRange(0x1F800, 0x1F8FF)   // Supplemental Arrows and Symbols
    );

private boolean isEmoji(int codePoint) {
        for (UnicodeRange range : EMOJI_RANGES) {
            if (range.contains(codePoint)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

private String removeEmojis(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int length = input.length();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < length) {
            int codePoint = input.codePointAt(i);

            if (Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint(codePoint)) {
                i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
                continue;
            }

            if (!isEmoji(codePoint)) {
                result.append(Character.toChars(codePoint));
            }

            i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

private byte[] generatePdfTranscript() throws IOException {
        if (ticketNumber != null) {
            fileName = ticketNumber + "_transcript.pdf";
        } else {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
            fileName = removeEmojis(customerName) + "_" + LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter) + "_transcript.pdf";
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            initializeFonts(document);

            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            document.addPage(page);

            try (PDPageContentStream initialContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
                float yPosition = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - MARGIN_Y;
                yPosition = setupPdfHeader(initialContentStream, yPosition, document);
                yPosition = addTranscriptTitle(initialContentStream, yPosition);

                PDPageContentStream currentContentStream = initialContentStream;

                for (Message message : messages) {
                    Pair<Float, PDPageContentStream> result = addMessage(document, currentContentStream, message, yPosition - 15);
                    yPosition = result.getLeft();

                    if (result.getRight() != currentContentStream) {
                        if (currentContentStream != initialContentStream) {
                            currentContentStream.close();
                        }
                        currentContentStream = result.getRight();
                    }
                }

                if (currentContentStream != initialContentStream) {
                    currentContentStream.close();
                }
            }

            document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

 private float setupPdfHeader(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float yPosition, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        contentStream.saveGraphicsState();

        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, FONT_SIZE);

        float pageWidth = document.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getWidth();

        float headerStartY = yPosition + 10;
        float contentWidth = pageWidth - 2 * MARGIN_X;

        if (ticketNumber != null) {
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Ticket Number: " + ticketNumber, yPosition);
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Date & Time Ticket Issued: " + issuedTime, yPosition);
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Date & Time Ticket Closed: " + closedTime, yPosition);
        } else {
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "No ticket issued", yPosition);
        }

        if (clientWhatsAppNumber != null) {
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Service's WhatsApp number: " + clientWhatsAppNumber, yPosition);
        }

        if (customerWhatsAppNumber != null) {
            yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Customer's WhatsApp number: " + customerWhatsAppNumber, yPosition);
        }

        yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Agent's Name & Surname: " + removeEmojis(agentName), yPosition);
        yPosition = addTextLine(contentStream, "Customer's Name & Surname: " + removeEmojis(customerName), yPosition);

        float headerHeight = headerStartY - yPosition + FONT_SIZE; // Add FONT_SIZE to give some bottom padding

        contentStream.setLineWidth(1f);
        contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        contentStream.addRect(MARGIN_X - 5, yPosition, contentWidth + 10, headerHeight);
        contentStream.stroke();

        contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();

        yPosition -= FONT_SIZE;

        return yPosition;
    }

    private float addTranscriptTitle(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float yPosition) throws IOException {
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, FONT_SIZE + 2);
        return addTextLine(contentStream, "Ticket Transcript:", yPosition - 20);
    }

I wrote unit tests for the username that was causing the error, and all the tests passed. I deployed the code to the staging server, and it worked as expected, successfully downloading the transcript for a username with emojis. However, on the live environment, it worked for some tickets with the same username but failed on others. After removing the emoji directly from the database, I was able to download the transcript for the ticket that was giving me an error.

U+1F413 is the 'rooster' emoji, so I'm not sure why your code did not remove it. If I had to guess, I'd say that your code in that particular case is not as you posted. You can probably simplify your code to private String removeEmojis(String input) {return input.codePoints().filter(c -> !isEmoji(c)).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();}

Character.isEmoji
As Commented by g00se, you can greatly simplify your emoji-removal code.
Java 21+ provides several methods on Character class to identify emoji: isEmoji, isEmojiPresentation, isEmojiModifier, isEmojiModifierBase, and isEmojiComponent. I have not studied these, and suggest that you do. But as an example I will guess that the following code will do.
String strippedOfEmoji =
        input
                .codePoints( )
                .filter( codepoint -> ! Character.isEmoji( codepoint ) )
                .filter( codepoint -> ! Character.isEmojiPresentation( codepoint ) )
                .filter( codepoint -> ! Character.isEmojiModifier( codepoint ) )
                .filter( codepoint -> ! Character.isEmojiComponent( codepoint ) )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString( );

Let's try that code.
String input = "abcxyz";


strippedOfEmoji = abcxyz

The Character class offers many such category-detection methods. Study those before attempting your own.
UTF-8
The real solution would be to change the character encoding of your terminal app from WinAnsiEncoding to UTF-8.
Then you should be able to see all of the 150,000 or so characters defined in Unicode, provided you have updated fonts.
Date-Time tips
By the way, some suggestions on your date-time handling.
I would re-use your DateTimeFormatter object rather than instantiating repeatedly. Move that code to be a static constant.
private static DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = … ;

And I suggest you always include an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Showing just date and time is ambiguous. The people reading that value can easily misinterpret. FYI, the letter Z is a standard character to indicate an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
For the same reason, you should not be using LocalDateTime here. That class represents a date with time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset. So its values are always ambiguous. So calling LocalDateTime.now never makes sense.
Generally best to use UTC time. And you could use simple string manipulation rather than a DateTimeFormatter object.
String output = Instant.now().toString().replace( "T" , "_" ).replace( ":" , "_" ) ;

Or use the moment as seen in a particular time zone. For this, use ZonedDateTime class, with a ZoneId. Its toString method generates text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.
You may want to truncate the fractional second.
String output = 
    ZonedDateTime
        .now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )  // Or else specify a particular time zone rather than use the JVM’s current default.
        .toString()            // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of time zone in square brackets. 
        .replace( "T" , "_" )  // Change the `T` in middle for easier reading by humans.
        .replace( ":" , "_" )  // Change COLON character used in legacy macOS file system as a path delimiter. 
        .replace( "/" , "_" )  // Change time zone name [Continent/Region] to avoid the slash (SOLIDUS) character used in Unix-oriented file systems as a path delimiter. 
;

See this code run at Ideone.com.

2024-09-27_15_26_47-06_00[America_Edmonton]

